# Errors getting Abstract class, interface, and extending class to implement generics without wildcard

Tags: java, generics

Its very clear from searching around on SO that this is a problem others have faced. However, I just cannot seem to get the solutions others have offered to compile using generics and not wildcards because of the extra complexity of the interface here.

The code below compiles, but I don't like that I'm using a wildcard and not a generic.

ListSorter.Java

```
import java.util.List;
public interface ListSorter <T> {
    public List<T> sort(List<T> list);
}
```

AbstractListSorterTest.java

```
package com.learning.test.algorithms;

import com.learning.algorithms.sorting.ListSorter;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import junit.framework.TestCase;

public abstract class AbstractListSorterTest extends TestCase {
    private List<String> unsortedStringList;
    private List<String> sortedStringList;

    // Eclipse shows "ListSorter is a raw type. References to generic type ListSorter<T> should be parameterized"
    protected abstract ListSorter createListSorter();

    public void testSortSimpleStrings() {
        ListSorter sorter = createListSorter();
        List<?> result = sorter.sort(unsortedStringList);

        assertEquals(unsortedStringList.size(), result.size());

        Iterator<?> actual = result.iterator();
        Iterator<?> expected = sortedStringList.iterator();

        while (actual.hasNext() && expected.hasNext()) {
          assertEquals(expected.next(), actual.next());
    }
 }
```

If I try the following:

```
List<T>  result = sorter.sort(unsortedStringList);
```

I get a compiler error "T cannot be resolved to a type" (which I get for a lot of different type of solutions).

**UPDATE**

Stuart's answer was spot on and I now have one warning left.

In BubblesortListSorterTest.java, I get the following warning:

```
The return type ListSorter<T> for createListSorter() from the type BubblesortListSorterTest<T> needs unchecked conversion to conform to ListSorter<Object> from the type AbstractListSorterTest
```

BubblesortListSorterTest.java

```
public class BubblesortListSorterTest<T extends Comparable<? super T>> extends AbstractListSorterTest {

  @Override
  protected ListSorter<T> createListSorter() {
    return new BubblesortListSorter<T>();
  }
}
```

**Update 2**

After making some additional changes, I finally got everything to work.

BubblesortListSorterTest.java

```
public class BubblesortListSorterTest extends AbstractListSorterTest {

  @Override
  protected <T extends Comparable<? super T>> ListSorter<T> createListSorter() {
    return new BubblesortListSorter<T>();
  }
}
```

AbstractListSorterTest.java

```
protected abstract <T extends Comparable<? super T>> ListSorter<T> createListSorter();


  public void testSortSimpleStrings() {
    ListSorter<String> sorter = createListSorter();
    List<String> result = sorter.sort(unsortedStringList);

    assertEquals(unsortedStringList.size(), result.size());

    Iterator<String> actual = result.iterator();
    Iterator<String> expected = sortedStringList.iterator();

    while (actual.hasNext() && expected.hasNext()) {
      assertEquals(expected.next(), actual.next());
    }
  }
```

ListSorter.java

```
public interface ListSorter <T> {
    public List<T> sort(List<T> list);
}
```

BubblesortListSorter.java

```
public class BubblesortListSorter <T extends Comparable<? super T>> implements ListSorter<T> {

  @Override
  public List<T> sort(List<T> list) {
    for (int outer = 1; outer < list.size(); outer++) {
      for (int left = 0; left < (list.size() - outer); left++) {
        int right = left + 1;
        if (list.get(left).compareTo(list.get(right)) > 0) {
          swap(list, left, right);
        }
      }
    }
    return list;
  }

  private void swap(List<T> list, int leftPos, int rightPos) {
    T temp = list.get(leftPos);
    list.set(leftPos, list.get(rightPos));
    list.set(rightPos, temp);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AbstractListSorterTest` wants to test a `ListSorter` implementation using a list of strings. So the test needs to tell whoever creates `ListSorter` that `T` should be `String`. If one were instantiating `ListSorter` directly (say, as an anonymous inner class) one would write something like

```
ListSorter<String> sorter = new ListSorter<String>() { ... };
```

Instead, you want the sorter instance to be created by an abstract method `createListSorter()`. Presumably something within this method is going to construct a `ListSorter` implementation. So you need to pass a type argument through `createListSorter()` so that it can in turn pass that argument to a `ListSorter` constructor. The way to do this is to make `createListSorter()` a generic method:

```
abstract <T> ListSorter<T> createListSorter();
```

Then change the point of call in the test to this:

```
ListSorter<String> sorter = createListSorter();
```

(The compiler infers that `T` is `String` in this case so that you don't have to pass an explicit type argument.)

At this point you can change the subsequent declarations from `Iterator<?>` to `Iterator<String>`.

The next issue you will run into is that the `ListSorter` implementation will not be able to sort objects of arbitrary type `T` since there is no way to compare them. Either you will have to pass in a comparator object to the `ListSorter` abstract factory and constructor, or you will have to add type bounds to ensure that `T` is a subtype of `Comparable`. Look at the `Collections.sort()` overloads in the [JDK documentation](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-) for ideas of the generic type signatures that need to be added.

Comment: Super helpful! Only one compiler warning left. "The return type ListSorter<T> for createListSorter() from the type BubblesortListSorterTest<T> needs unchecked conversion to conform to ListSorter<Object> from the type AbstractListSorterTest BubblesortListSorterTest.java"

Comment: Not sure where `ListSorter<Object>` is coming from. I'd have to see the code. You might have to specify an explicit type in the create call, for example, `ListSorter<Foo> sorter = this.<Foo>createListSorter()`.

Comment: I posted two updates and it is now 100% working. Most of the code is above. Thanks a million!